# WPF Combobox displaying hierarchical data

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a table of categories in my database, as below.

Category

- categoryId
- name
- parentId

The parentId links back to itself to form hierarchy.

How do I bind it to a combobox in WPF so that the child elements are indented as appropriate for each level?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what exactly you mean? ASCII drawing? Draw something in MSPAINT?

Comment: Maybe a DataTemplate with a Tree?

Comment: I would prefer a combobox as otherwise a tree is such a waste of space, especially on a small touchscreen app. I can get the data back in a hierachical fashion, I just need to indent or change the line somehow when a certain field is set to a value. For example I can add a column to show the level each element is on. e.g. 1, 2, 3. Is there a way in the combobox to change formatting of a line dependant upon the value of a column in the data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="{Binding Level, Converter={x:Static my:MainWindow.LevelToMarginConverter}}" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

C#:

```
class MainWindow {
    ......
    class LevelToMarginConverterClass : IValueConverter {
        const int onelevelmargin = 10;
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            int level = (int)value;
            return new Thickness(level * onelevelmargin,0,0,0);
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static IValueConverter LevelToMarginConverter = new LevelToMarginConverterClass();
}
```

Be sure to have `int Level` and `string Name` properties in your class